# Наследование дескрипторов в Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows

Нужно передать готовое соединение другом процессу. Прочитал про наследование дескрипторов на msdn, но примеров не нашел. Как именно мне получит доступ к наследуемуму дескриптору сокета? Где он лежит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы «другой» (дочерний) процесс мог получить доступ к дескриптору, открытому в вашем процессе, необходимо выполнить две вещи:

1. Сделать дескриптор наследуемым (изначально создав его таким, либо склонировав через `DuplicateHandle()` с параметром `bInheritHandle == true`). Это сделает дескриптор видимым из дочернего процесса.
2. Передать собственно дескриптор (четырёхбайтное целое число). Как это сделать — решайте сами. Можете воспользоваться стандартным потоком ввода/вывода, или открыть именованный канал, или послать оконное сообщение главному окну дочерней программы, или даже указать его в качестве параметра командной строки дочернего процесса, если дескриптор был открыт до вызова `CreateProcess()`.

Если же вы попытаетесь передать дескриптор, для которого наследование разрешено не было, дочерний процесс не сможет получить к нему доступ, будто его не существует.

> Где он лежит?

В ядре операционной системы, как обычно. Изменяется лишь проверка прав доступа при обращении к объекту за дескриптором. По умолчанию требуется точное соответствие обращающегося процесса и процесса-создателя. При включении же наследования критерий соответствия превращается из «только создатель» в «создатель и его потомки».

К слову, с помощью такой штуки, как DACL (передаваемой через параметры типа `LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`) можно задавать ещё более гибкие разрешения.

Comment: Т.е. мне достаточно `reinterpret_cast<char>(SOCKET)`, передать как угодно и восстановить его в собственно обратно? Именно этот момент непонятен. Хотя достаточно просто передать `long`.

Comment: @MrBin, `reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(SOCKET)`. *и восстановить его в собственно обратно* — да, с помощью `reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(number)`. Дальше работаете с переданным дескриптором как обычно.

Comment: Этот ответ неверный, Согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx) `DuplicateHandle` нельзя использовать для дублирования дескрипторов сокетов: *You should not use DuplicateHandle to duplicate handles to the following objects: Sockets. No error is returned, but the duplicate handle may not be recognized by Winsock at the target process.*

Comment: @VTT, в данном случае я проигнорировал часть про дублирование. Я это уже читал. Меня больше интересовала сама передача.

Answer (score 4):

Для дублирования дескрипторов сокетов следует использовать специальную функцию [WSADuplicateSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741565(v=vs.85).aspx). Ее работа отличается от обычной `DuplicateHandle`, вместо нового дескриптора она заполняет структуру `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO`, которую необходимо самостоятельно передать в другой процесс и использовать для вызова `WSASocket` в нем.